# Sending information from model to view, MVC architecture, PyQT5

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt5

I'm trying to create an application with PyQT5 using the MVC architecture and I'm having trouble understanding how to send some of the information from the model to the view. In the sample application below, I have a countdown timer running in the model and I'd like the progress bar in the View to track it's progress. But I'm unsure how to send information to the view from the model when the method in the model is being executed. In my case, the progress_bar gets updated only after the execution of the model.counter method has completed executed. What would be a graceful way of handling this ? I need the progress_bar to update as model.i gets updated.

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class ExampleGUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Sample Application')
        # Set some main window's properties
        self.setFixedSize(235, 235)
        # Set the central widget and the general layout
        self.generalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)
        # Create the display and the buttons
        self._createDisplay()
        self._createButtons()

    def _createDisplay(self):
        """Create the display."""
        # Create the display widget
        self.display = QLineEdit()
        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar()
        # Set some display's properties
        self.display.setFixedHeight(35)
        self.display.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.display.setReadOnly(True)
        # Add the display to the general layout
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.display)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.progress_bar)

    def _createButtons(self):
        """Create the buttons."""
        buttonsLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Start")
        self.button1.setFixedSize(80, 40)
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Clear")
        self.button2.setFixedSize(80, 40)
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.button1)
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.generalLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)

    def setDisplayText(self, text):
        """Set display's text."""
        self.display.setText(text)
        self.display.setFocus()

    def clearDisplay(self):
        """Clear the display."""
        self.setDisplayText("")


class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = ''
        self.i = ''

    def countdown(self, counter):
        self.i = 0
        self.counter = counter
        while self.i < self.counter:
            self.i+=1
            time.sleep(1)
        return True


class Controller:
    def __init__(self, view, model):
        self._view = view
        self._model = model
        self._connect_settings_signals()

    def _set_message(self):
        self._view.progress_bar.setMaximum(10)
        reply = self._model.countdown(10)
        self._view.progress_bar.setValue(self._model.i)
        if reply:
            self._view.setDisplayText("Countdown complete!")

    def _clear_message(self):
        self._view.clearDisplay()

    def _connect_settings_signals(self):
        self._view.button1.clicked.connect(self._set_message)
        self._view.button2.clicked.connect(self._clear_message)


def main():
    """Main function."""
    # Create an instance of `QApplication`
    pycalc = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Show the calculator's GUI
    view = ExampleGUI()
    view.show()
    model = Model()
    # Create instances of the model and the controller
    ctrl = Controller(view=view, model=model)
    # Execute calculator's main loop
    sys.exit(pycalc.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

That sleep(1) is blocking operation and event loop returns to '_set_message' only after 'countdown' is finished. 
I would move update of model and loop out of model, back to controller. (As its kind of controlling, telling model update its value, wait a bit...)

I would update to something similar as:

```
    def _set_message(self):
        self._view.progress_bar.setMaximum(10)

        self.i = 0
        while self.i < 10:
            self.i+=1

            self._model.i += 1
            self._view.progress_bar.setValue(self._model.i)
            time.sleep(1)

        self._view.setDisplayText("Countdown complete!")
```

If you would insist on looping and sleeping in model (I don't think thats a good idea), you would have to dive into threading, create separate thread for that operation, and keep main event loop unblocked for redrawing of progress bar. (imho)

Comment: My actual application does a lot more than just doing a countdown so it'd be hard to bring all that functionality into the controller. With running the application running in a different thread, would I be able to send back information from the model to the controller to thereby update the progress_bar ?

Comment: Yes, you can emit signal from that thread. I think I saw something similar here https://youtu.be/ivcxZSHL7jM?t=1058